# Facing issue in restricting the amount of splits

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have used the below code to split my string.

```
splitter.map((item1) => {
 let splitter1 = item1.split("=")[0].trimLeft();
 let splitter2 = item1.split("=")[1].trimRight();
});
```

where item1 contains string as

```
Labor_Agreement=0349BP 
Default_Hours=5/8 
Probation_Period=>=12 Months
```

The issue I am facing is to restrict the amount of splits. Because the above code will fail in case of third string , i.e. `Probation_Period=>=12 Months`

I tried giving parameter to restrict the amount of split in split method above, but that is giving syntax error.

Comment: So what should happen with the `Probation_Period=>=12 Months` string ? What will the output look like ?

Comment: Output is ">", it should be ">=12Months"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy to understand solution would consist of first finding the first `=` character, and slicing you array twice to get the right portion :

```js
const strings = [
    'Labor_Agreement=0349BP',
    'Default_Hours=5/8',
    'Probation_Period=>=12 Months',
];

strings.map(item => {
    const chSplit = item.indexOf('=');
    const splitter1 = item.slice(0, chSplit).trim();
    const splitter2 = item.slice(chSplit + 1).trim();
    console.log(splitter1, splitter2);
});
```